# Click to swap elements between two lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, dom, sortablejs

I'm using SortableJS to build a menu where hash-tag like label items can be dragged from a search result area to another area where they will be counted. I've got the drag-drop functionality working between the two lists. **Now what I want to do is add click functionality so that when a tag item in one list is clicked it moves to the opposite list.**

This should help users who don't expect to have to drag-drop, or who would rather click. The goal is to accommodate a broad range of user devices (mobile/desktop) and computer literacy (tech-savvy/not tech-savvy).

[Here is an example of Shared Lists using SortableJS.](https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#shared-lists)

[image: SortableJS shared lists. These items can be drag-dropped between lists, but I want them to be clickable.]

Both lists share the class `list-group`, which enables them to share items with each other.

I've been looking into the possibility of creating a script that gets the div element that is clicked on (from either list), removes it, and instantly re-adds to the opposite list, with all the div attributes and contents in tact. But maybe modifying the existing SortableJS code is a better approach?

--
As a quick test, I bypassed the UI and changed the order of the items purely in HTML using Developer Tools, and it didn't break the functionality. So doing the same with a script should work.

Currently I am researching how to have any item of a given class, when clicked on, removed from a parent element and then made a child of another parent element (the other list).

--
I found [a simple and elegant jQuery script](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/move-clicked-list-items-to-top-of-list/) that seems promising for this sort of thing. I started to modify it to support two lists, but unfortunately, after multiple swaps it stops working correctly. Hopefully with some modification it can be made to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
 div {
  width: 180px;
  padding: 2px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" style="background-color: #a55">
<p class="swappable">Paragraph one.</p>
<p class="swappable">Paragraph two.</p>
</div>

<div id="div2" style="background-color: #bab1e5">
<p class="swappable">Paragraph three.</p>
<p class="swappable">Paragraph four.</p>
</div>

<script>
$("#div1 p").click(function() {
 
 $("#div2").append($(this));
 
});

$("#div2 p").click(function() {
 
 $("#div1").append($(this));
 
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Scanning through [the documentation for jQuery's .append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check out SortableJS' next-version branch `swap` mode: https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/tree/next-version#swap-option

Comment: @OwenM I downloaded the "next version", enabled `swap`, and tried it out. While that feature is useful as well, it's different from what I was trying to do in this case. I needed items that could be moved whether dragged *or* clicked. I suppose this is my chance to make a feature request? Please consider a `clickable` option for dual-list configurations (Shared Lists and Cloning). For now, Parth Jasani's answer has enabled jQuery to be a solution for me. SortableJS is a really handy library, and I've found it fairly easy to customize/implement, so thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use on click method of jQuery

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div {
        width: 180px;
        padding: 2px 12px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" style="background-color: #a55">
<p class="swappable">Paragraph one.</p>
<p class="swappable">Paragraph two.</p>
</div>

<div id="div2" style="background-color: #bab1e5">
<p class="swappable">Paragraph three.</p>
<p class="swappable">Paragraph four.</p>
</div>

<script>
$("#div1").on("click","p",function() {
    $("#div2").append($(this));

});

$("#div2").on("click","p",function() {
    $("#div1").append($(this));
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly! Do you know what I did wrong in my syntax? I don't want to make the same mistake again.

Comment: when you want to perform any events on a dynamic element like here "p" tag is dynamic because p tag will be appended or detach and #div1 and #div2 are static elements so in this case, you need to tell to jQuery that p tag is dynamic in #div using on method